problem to send udp packet with ncat and Windows 11
I use ncat on Windows 10 and 11 with powershell
My script :
"1111" | ncat -w1 -n "10.10.10.255" -u 1234

On Windows 10, "1111" is sent ([31 31 31 31 0d a0]): it is OK.
On Windows 11, before "1111",  [ef bb bf] is inserted ([ef bb bf 31 31 31 31 0d a0]): it is not OK.
[ef bb bf] is BOM sequence.
How to do ?

Looks like it is defaulting to IP V6 instead 0f IP V4.  See if -4 option works.  I found documentation that has option -6, but no -4.

Is there a way to test this with ncat --listen --udp?  tcp works fine

'11' | ncat localhost -u works for me in win11, anything larger gets a buffer error

@js2010  do you see my problem with my code? You can use Wireshark to capture packets.

I found a solution without ncat but it doesn't explain why there is a problem with ncat : $client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
$data = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("1111" + "rn")
$client.Send($data, $data.Length, "10.10.10.255", 1234)

@jdweng I don't think that problem is IPv4. I thing Powershell create a virtual file with BOM and it sent to ncat.

It depends on which ncat it is.  I'm using the nmap one.
